# *apply in r to repeat a function

Tags: r

I've written a function that is a simulation, that outputs a vector of 100 elements, and I want to use the `*apply` functions to run the function many times and store the repeated output in a new vector for each time the simulation is run.

The function looks like:

```
J <- c(1:100)
species_richness <- function(J){
   a <- table(J)
   return(NROW(a))
}

simulation <- function(J,gens,ploton=FALSE,v=0.1){
    species_richness_output <- rep(NA,gens)
    for(rep in 1:gens){
        index1 <- sample(1:length(J),1)

        if(runif(1,0,1) < v){
           J[index1] <- (rep+100)
        } 
        else{
           index2 <- sample(1:length(J),1)
           while(index1==index2) {
               index2 <- sample(1:length(J),1)
           }
           J[index1] <- J[index2]
        }
        species_richness_output[rep] <- species_richness(J)
    }

    species_abundance <- function(J){
       a <- table(J)
       return(a)
    }

    abuntable <- species_abundance(J)
    print(abuntable)

    octaves <- function(abuntable){
       oct <- (rep(0,log2(sum(abuntable))))

       for(i in 1:length(abuntable)){
          oct2 <- floor(log2(abuntable[i])+1)
          oct[oct2] <- oct[oct2]+1
       }

       print(oct)
    }   

    # octaves(c(100,64,63,5,4,3,2,2,1,1,1,1))


    if(ploton==TRUE){
       hist(octaves(abuntable))
    }
    print(species_richness(J))

    return(J)
}

simulation(J, 10000,TRUE,v=0.1)
```

So that's my function, it takes J a vector I defined earlier, manipulates it, then returns:
the newly simulated vector J of 100 elements
a function called octave that categorises the new vector
a histogram corresponding to the above "octave"

I have tried a number of variations: using `lapply`, `mapply` 
putting `args=args_from_original_simulation`

```
simulation_repeated <- c(mapply(list, FUN=simulation(args),times=10000))
```

but I keep getting an error with the match.fun part of the mapply function

```
Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
  'simulation(J, 10000, FALSE, 0.1)' is not a function, character or symbol
```

This is despite the simulation I have written showing as being saved as a function in the workspace.

Does anyone know what this error is pointing to?

Comment: Maybe `replicate` is closer to what you're looking for...?

Comment: the sample code you've supplied looks FUBAR. Are your `args` varying from one simulation to the next? If not, than `joran`s got the right idea.

Comment: or `r*ply` from the `ddply` package

Comment: I'd also suggest you avoid naming variables with names of critical functions like `args`.  If you supply a little more info, like the body of your `simulation` function and `args` you'll get a lot more specific answers.

Comment: i've gotten that error when passing in arguments to one of the pply functions before. Typically if you wrap the whole body in an anonymous function then it works.

Comment: I've added the body of the function. I've tried a number of different variations of the mapply function, at one point it was creating new matrices but filling them with steps i.e if I asked for 10000 simulations it produced 10000 matrices going up 1,2,3,4...

Comment: I tried to reformat your code into something that is at least readable, but I can't make sense of it the way it's indented at the moment. I still recommend using `replicate`, but I can't be more specific than that if I can't even understand your code. Now that I think about it, that error message would fit with you having some fatal syntax errors, which would also fit with my inability to decode and reformat your code into something sensible.

Comment: What's wrong with my code? It works and returns the stuff I want it to I'm not getting error messages when the actual function runs. Ill add comments

Comment: The formatting is atrocious, which makes it nearly impossible to read.

Comment: I _think_ I got that right, but I'm not sure. Please, please, please indent your code better! :)

Comment: I've just gotten it to work by doing:                                             simulated_results<-replicate(n=100,simulation(J,10000,FALSE,0.1),simplify="matrix") 

but its running the simulation slower than in the original function

Comment: @user1987097 That would take 100 time longer than the original one if for no other reason, it is running the simulation 100 times. Or is it even slower than that?

Comment: It's running one simulation slower than the original.

Comment: @user1987097 that is unlikely - please provide some timings with `system.time()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
simulation_repeated <- c(mapply(list, FUN=simulation(args),times=10000))
```

You are not giving a function to mapply.  You are (essentially) passing the result of calling `simulation(args)` and `simulation` does not return a function.